# como se puede agregar un nuevo tabla a la base de datos

Tags: java, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Buenas mira el problema es que estoy creando una aplicación en la que el usuario ingresa su nombre y su nota y asi guardarlos en la base de datos, el problema viene cuando intento crear la tabla en netbeans, os dejo el codigo:

```
 public void crearTablabd() throws InstantiationException, 
 IllegalAccessException, SQLException{

  try {
      Connection conn = null;

      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn = 

     DriverManager.getConnection
  ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/osapiensef", 
  "root", "quepasachavales3");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
    String notabd= vIngreso.getTxtNombre().getText();
    String sql=( "CREATE TABLE osapiensef" + (notabd) + "Nombre TEXT 
     NOT NULL ");
    st.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Ingreso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
    ex);
 }

     }
```

El fallo que me da la consola es que la sentencia sql esta mal escrita pero he buscado por muchos foros y esta igual, espero que poeais ayudarme, gracias de ante mano.

Comment: Puede colocar el código de error que se presenta.

Comment: GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Nombre TEXT NOT NULL' at line 1

Comment: sin saber el valor de notabd no podemos ver el problema, pero la falta de espacios antes y después se ve algo sospechoso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

como te pone en la pila de errores tu error es de sintaxis, te pongo un método completo  y tu adáptalo a tus necesidades

```
public static void crearTabla() {

     String nameTable = "Nombre_tabla";
     String nameField = "Nombre_campo";
     Connection conn = null;
     Statement st = null;
     try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/pruebas", "root", "");
        st = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + nameTable + " (" + nameField +  " VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL)";
        st.execute(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

La linea clave es

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + nameTable + " (" + nameField +  " VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL)";
```

Haz las modificaciones pertinentes y no tendrás problema.
Saludos